# wget a file stored on local host from within wsl2 ubuntu hosted on the same machine

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wget

Why I do this:
I'm building a docker image from dockerfile which specifies several large files to be wget-ed from various locations, problem is, bad network.
Now I've managed to get all the required files on the local host, I hope there is a way to simply modify the wget locations in the dockerfile to solve this problem.

What I did:
I set up a http server with the `python3 -m http.server` command from the directory in which I stored the desired files.
I then tried accessing the files via a browser and then CLI on another machine under the same lan, it worked fine with the browser, but the wget command `wget http://<host IP>:8000/<filename>` always stops at "waiting for response".
As for the Ubuntu on wsl, the wget command didn't even manage to establish connection.

I must've missed a few steps, but what are them?

Hence the question.

Comment: Alright...I think I solved my own problem.

Comment: If you have, then I'd ask that you either (a) post it as an answer (and accept it once allowed), or (b) (since there are currently no answers) delete the question.  Otherwise, questions without accepted answers are occasionally "bumped" by the bot here to see if someone can answer it for you.  Thanks!

Comment: @刘刘天阳 please do tell what your solution is!